# Efficiently generate primes in Python and calculate complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

Generating prime numbers from 1 to n Python 3. How to improve efficiency and what is the complexity?

Input: A number, max (a large number)
Output: All the primes from 1 to max
Output is in the form of a list and will be [2,3,5,7,11,13,.......]
The code attempts to perform this task in an efficient way (least time complexity).

```
from math import sqrt    
max = (10**6)*3
print("\nThis code prints all primes till: " , max , "\n")
list_primes=[2]

def am_i_prime(num):
    """
    Input/Parameter the function takes: An integer number
    Output: returns True, if the number is prime and False if not
    """ 
    decision=True
    i=0
    while(list_primes[i] <= sqrt(num)): #Till sqrt(n) to save comparisons
        if(num%list_primes[i]==0):
            decision=False
            break
                    #break is inserted so that we get out of comparisons faster
                    #Eg. for 1568, we should break from the loop as soon as we know that 1568%2==0
        i+=1
    return decision


for i in range(3,max,2):  #starts from 3 as our list contains 2 from the beginning
    if am_i_prime(i)==True:
    list_primes.append(i)  #if a number is found to be prime, we append it to our list of primes

print(list_primes)
```

How can I make this faster? Where can I improve?
What is the time complexity of this code? Which steps are inefficient?
In what ways is the Sieve of Eratosthenes more efficient than this?

Working for the first few iterations:-

1. We have a `list_primes` which contains prime numbers. It initially contains only 2.
2. We go to the next number, 3. Is 3 divisible by any of the numbers in `list_primes`? No! We append 3 to `list_primes`. Right now, `list_primes=[2,3]`
3. We go to the next number 4. Is 4 divisible by any of the numbers in `list_primes`? Yes (4 is divisible by 2). So, we don't do anything. Right now `list_primes=[2,3]`
4. We go to the next number, 5. Is 5 divisible by any of the numbers in `list_primes`? No! We append 5 to list_primes. Right now, `list_primes=[2,3,5]`
5. We go to the next number, 6. Is 6 divisible by any of the numbers in list_primes? Yes (6 is divisible by 2 and also divisible by 3). So, we don't do anything. Right now `list_primes=[2,3,5]`
6. And so on...

Comment: FWIW, I'd remove the calculation of ```sqrt(num)``` from the loop condition. It's expensive to calculate and it does not change, so compute it once only.  Maybe it can get optimized out automatically, but I would not count on it.

Comment: Yeah, makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly, it takes a rather deep mathematical theorem to prove that your algorithm is correct at all. The theorem is: "For every n ≥ 2, there is a prime number between n and n^2". I know it has been proven, and much stricter bounds are proven, but I must admit I wouldn't know how to prove it myself. And if this theorem is not correct, then the loop in am_i_prime can go past the bounds of the array.

The number of primes ≤ k is O (k / log k) - this is again a very deep mathematical theorem. Again, beyond me to prove.

But anyway, there are about n / log n primes up to n, and for these primes the loop will iterate through all primes up to n^(1/2), and there are O (n^(1/2) / log n) of them.

So for the primes alone, the runtime is therefore O (n^1.5 / log^2 n), so that is a lower bound. With some effort it should be possible to prove that for all numbers, the runtime is asymptotically the same.

O (n^1.5 / log n) is obviously an upper bound, but experimentally the number of divisions to find all primes ≤ n seems to be ≤ 2 n^1.5 / log^2 n, where log is the natural logarithm.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Where did you get O (n^1.5 / log n) from?    O (n^1.5 / log^2 n )makes sense cause n^1.5 / log^2 n = (n^1/2 * log n) * (n / log n) , which is time it takes for one prime * number of primes

Comment: I understood my mistake. Let us assume m = sqrt(n). There are m/logm primes till m, and for each number we are performing sqrt(m) comparisons. Thus, (m/logm)   *     m   =  m^1.5 / m is time complexity

Answer (score 0):

The following rearrangement and optimization of your code will reach your maximum in nearly 1/2 the time of your original code.  It combines your top level loop and predicate function into a single function to eliminate overhead and manages squares (square roots) more efficiently:

```
def get_primes(maximum):
    primes = []

    if maximum > 1:
        primes.append(2)
        squares = [4]

        for number in range(3, maximum, 2):
            i = 0

            while squares[i] <= number:
                if number % primes[i] == 0:
                    break

                i += 1
            else:  # no break
                primes.append(number)
                squares.append(number * number)

    return primes

maximum = 10 ** 6 * 3
print(get_primes(maximum))
```

However, a sieve-based algorithm will easily beat this (as it avoids division and/or multiplication).  Your code has a bug: setting `max = 1` will create the list `[2]` instead of the correct answer of an empty list.  Always test both ends of your limits.

Answer (score -1):

O(N**2)

Approximately speaking, the first call to `am_I_prime` does 1 comparison, the second does 2, ..., so the total count is 1 + 2 + ... + N, which is (N * (N-1)) / 2, which has order N-squared.

Comment: Please read the code more carefully. It is obvious that it takes no more than O (N^1.5), but in reality (this requires bit of math) it takes O (N^1.5) / log^2 N.